# Using compareTo(String) get error says undefined for the type String

Tags: java, string, tree, compareto

```
public node add(String newWord, int ln, node cur) {
       if (cur == null) {
           return new node(newWord,ln);
       }

       int result=newWord.compareTo(cur.word); //compareTo is underlined suggesting an error


       if ( result == 0) ;
       else if (result < 0) {
           cur.left = add(newWord,ln, cur.left);
       } else {
           cur.right = add(newWord,ln, cur.right);
       }
       return cur;
   }

   public void add(String word, int ln) {
       root = add(word,ln, root);
   }
```

I'm using Eclipse, and the red underline says

> "The method compareTo(String) is undefined for the type String"

. How can I fix this?

treemap code.. about the node.

```
class treemap<String, Integer> {

   private class node {
      String word;
      int line;
      node left;
      node right;

      node(String wd, int ln){
          word=wd;
          line=ln;
      }
   }
   private node root;

   public treemap(){
       root=null;
   }
```

This is what shows when I use javac:

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> int result=newWord.compareTo("test");
>
> symbol: method compareTo
>
> location: variable newWord of type String
>
> where String is a type-variable:
>
> String extends Object declared in class treemap

I tried to replace newWord with a string "hello", then the underline disappeared. but how can I fix this?

Comment: is this all in the same class?

Comment: yes they are in the same class

Comment: This is bizarre, as String most certainly has a compareTo(String) method. Have you tried compiling from the command line with javac?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: no..it will work if it's private?

Comment: @JoeAttardi: I tried javac, it says "cannot find symbol". "location: variable newWord of type String"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "String" is not `java.lang.String`, it is a type parameter declared with the definition of the treemap class.
You are working in a generic class, and `String` is a type variable of this class.

In other words, this :

```
class treemap<String, Integer> {

   private class node {
      String word;
      int line;
      node left;
      node right;

      node(String wd, int ln){
          word=wd;
          line=ln;
      }
   }
   private node root;

   public treemap(){
       root=null;
   }
```

...Has the same meaning that this :

```
class treemap<T, U> {

   private class node {
      T word;
      int line;
      node left;
      node right;

      node(T wd, int ln){
          word=wd;
          line=ln;
      }
   }
   private node root;

   public treemap(){
       root=null;
   }
```

If you want T to extend String and U to extend Integer, then you should define your class like that :

```
class treemap<T extends String, U extends Integer> {
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the parameter 'cur.word' is causing this. Try replacing it temporarily with "test" to see if the compilation error goes.

I think cur.word isn't accessible

Comment: I tried test=cur.word, and test=cur and compareTo(test.word), it does not work. Is this what you want me to do?

Comment: Replace cur.word with "hello". This will probe if the parameter is causing it or not.

Comment: first, put in a manual string where cur.word is.  like "test". see what happens, let us know.

Comment: @iamthereplicant:  i tried to replace newWord with "test", the underline disappeared. but I don't know how to fix this.. help?

Comment: Remove the generic <String, Integer> from the class declaration.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use equal(). Here is an example:

```
String one = "Dog";
String two = "dog";
if (one.equalsIgnoreCase(two)) {
  System.out.println("Words are the same");
} else {
  System.out.println("Words are not the same");
}

if (one.equals(two)) {
    System.out.println("Words are the same- Caste Sensative");
} else {
    System.out.println("Words are not the same -- Caste Sensative ");
}
```

Comment: but I don't want to use equal.. I want to sort the word